# SDL_mixer требует SDL.dll

Tags: c, sdl, sdl2

Я осваиваюсь с **SDL2**. В целом проблем нет, разобрался, как подключать эту библиотеку к проекту без расширений. Все работает.

Хотел бы использовать расширения этой библиотеки - **SDL_image** и **SDL_mixer**.

Делаю все так, как написано в этом туториале:
http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson03/windows/codeblocks/index.php

После выполнения всего, что нужно, необходимые мне функции находятся и проект даже собирается. Но при запуске появляется сообщение с информацией о том, что **SDL.dll** не найден.

У меня вообще этого файла нет, потому что я использую **SDL2** и файл **SDL2.dll**.

Я не совсем понимаю, в чем заключается проблема.

Вопросы такие:

1) **SDL_mixer** не может работать с **SDL2**?

2) Чем отличается **SDL** от **SDL2**?

3) Если **SDL2** - это более современная версия библиотеки, позволяет ли она загружать изображения в формате **png/jpg** и удобно воспроизводить звук, или и ей, **SDL2**, тоже нужны расширения?

Comment: Туториал написан для sdl1.x, бинарники для этой версии вы можете взять на официальном сайте: [SDL version 1.2.15 (historic)](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php)

Comment: [SDL_mixer 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/)

Comment: Вам нужны не SDL_image и SDL_mixer, а SDL2_image и SDL2_mixer - для новой версии SDL.

Comment: Спасибо большое!